# Complexe filter in a collection

Tags: filter, collection-filtering

I would like to use addFieldToFilter (or other...) in a collection to make this filter :

> (item1 = 'value' AND (item2 = 'value1' OR item = 'value2')) OR (item2 = 'value3' OR item = 'value4')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever dealing with complex filters, I prefer to work with the underlying `Zend_Db_Select` object. For example:

```
$collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->where(
        new Zend_Db_Expr("(item1 = '?' AND (item2 = '?' OR item = '?')) OR (item2 = '?' OR item = '?')"), 
        'value1', 
        'value2', 
        'value3', 
        'value4'
    );
```